# Angular 4.3 httpclient empty response headers

Tags: django, angular, httpclient

I have an Django backend. And trying to get http headers from it by using:
1) Angular 4.3 Http (it is going to be deprecated)
2) Plain XmlHttprequest.
3) Angular 4.3 HttpClient

1) and 2) have headers. But 3) does not.

---

Headers from 1):

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(xhttp.getAllResponseHeaders());
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8000/csbg/survey/sometest/", true);
xhttp.send();
```

---

Headers from 2):

```
import { HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

     this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/csbg/survey/sometest/')
     .subscribe(
       data=>{
         console.log('GET OK')
         console.log(data)
       },
       error=>{
         console.log("GET ERROR: " + error);
       }
     )
```

[Headers from (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Shcwg.png)

---

Headers from 3):

```
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'

  this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/csbg/survey/sometest/', { observe: 'response' })
  .subscribe(
    data=>{
      console.log('GET OK')
      console.log(data)
    },
    error=>{
      console.log("GET ERROR: " + error);
    }
  )
```

[There is no headers ! Why?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GfIR.png)

Also, Why default Access-Control-Expose-Headers headers is not present in there:

By default, only the 6 simple response headers are exposed:

Cache-Control
Content-Language
Content-Type
Expires
Last-Modified
Pragma

but my custom header is ?

Comment: The docs show accessing an arbitrary header: https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response. What happens if you explicitly try to get the one you’re looking for?

Comment: Thanks for you help. When I explicitly query for an header:
    var hdr = data.headers.get('asdf')

all headers are appeared in console.log(data)
The problem is solved. Thank you.

It is a little strange though :)

Comment: And toward a default Access-Control-Expose-Headers header. As I understood, it only allows to send headers.  But do nothing to set them.

Comment: I assume the headers are only parsed lazily then, as you request them, to make all the times you don’t need to access any more efficient.

Comment: @AndriyKutsevol Is there already a solution to get for example content-disposition? because I am trying that right now but I always get null.