# angular 2 - httpClient is returning empty headers

Tags: angular

I am executing a web service using httpClient, but my problem is that the response headers are always empty, I already check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389488/angular-4-3-httpclient-empty-response-headers) and [this](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response) and can't make it work, this is my service:

```
iniciarSesion(usuario: Usuario) {

const idSistema = environment.idSistema;
const url = environment.url + environment.mssesiones;
return this.httpClient.post(
  url,
  {
    usuario: usuario.usuario,
    contrasena: usuario.contrasena,
    idSistema: idSistema
  },
  {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    }),
    observe : 'response'
  });
}
```

And this is the component that execute the service:

```
this.inicioSesionService.iniciarSesion(usuario).subscribe(
        (httpResponse: HttpResponse<Object>) => {
          console.log(httpResponse);
      });
```

Can someone help me with this issue?,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching I found that the problem was the service(spring boot service), I needed to add the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` like this:

```
headers.add("authorization", jwtUtil.generateToken(usuario, peticion.getRemoteAddr()));
headers.add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "authorization");
```

I notice that the httpResponse was returning empty headers until I execute:

```
httpResponse.headers.get('authorization');
```

After that execution the console.log display the header information, I don't understand the behavior of that but now is working.

Comment: I also faced similar issue. I've set headers from server side to allow & expose all required headers. But still I keep getting empty headers in client side (Angular 6).

But when I execute 
`response.headers.get('Content-Type');`
suddenly, I get all headers!!!